# How to solve the AppStore rejection issue

Tags: ios

I have an App (EOL) which is a platform for easy online liquidation whereby sellers and buyers meet up to sell their non-moving stocks. Apple Rejected it saying, I cannot put non-IOS products(Android phones) in the list. Can Anyone help me as to how do I solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: Explain in detail, your app rejection reason, Provide a screenshot if possible.

Comment: They are probably referring to the screenshots in your app metadata. You cannot show Android devices in those. When people are using your app you can have them.

Comment: There are other apps that sell Android phones (for example Aliexpress). My guess is that you have a direct mention of Android somewhere in the app (for example, a category) or app store description, which Apple has a problem with. Without more info we can only guess.

Comment: i am agree with @NikolaLajic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because app store related questions are considered off-topic, see [here for more information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)